# Determine if the following series converges or diverges

Tags: calculus

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{8n+4}{\sqrt{10n^4 + 10n + 9}}$

When we solve do we ignore the square root and solve like a regular problem?

Comment: Study convergence tests. For example ratio test. Compare vs $1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac{8n+4}{\sqrt{10n^4+10n+9}}\ge\frac{8n}{\sqrt{30n^4}}\ge\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

$8n + 4 > n$, and $10n^4 + 10n + 9 < 100n^4$. So $\dfrac{8n+4}{\sqrt{10n^4 + 10n + 9}} > \dfrac{n}{10n^2} = \dfrac{1}{10n}$, and since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{10n}$ diverges to $+\infty$, the original series diverges to $+\infty$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another way,

$ > \frac{8n+4}{\sqrt{64(n+2)^4}} = \frac{8n+4}{8(n+2)^2} = \frac{1}{n+2}$ so from harmonic series...